# Check box on UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I created `UITableView` with a checkbox on each `cell`. This is how I did it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";
    ExtraCell *eCell = (ExtraCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (eCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib;

        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExtraCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ExtraCell class]])
            eCell = (ExtraCell *)oneObject;

    }
    int flag = (1 << indexPath.row);

    // update row's accessory if it's "turned on"
    if (checkboxSelections & flag)
        eCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    eCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return eCell;
}
```

And `UITableView`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as follows

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    checkboxSelections ^= (1 << indexPath.row);
    [self.tblViewExtra reloadData];

    NSLog(@"CheckBox selections %d", checkboxSelections);

}
```

Here, `checkboxSelections` is a `NSUInteger`. `checkboxSelections` accumulate all selected rows as single bits of that integer. My question is How can I get selected rows as an array or set of row numbers?

Comment: If I understood qn correctly, why dont you add the rows in an NSMutableArray in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @sajaz what you store in your array? any Class Object?

Comment: checkboxSelections ^= (1 << indexPath.row); ?????? can you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like that,

In `.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *selectedRows;
```

In `.m`

@synthesis selectedRows;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";
    ExtraCell *eCell = (ExtraCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (eCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib;

        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExtraCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ExtraCell class]])
            eCell = (ExtraCell *)oneObject;

    }
    int flag = (1 << indexPath.row);

    // update row's accessory if it's "turned on"

    NSString *rowString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    if (checkboxSelections & flag) {
        eCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        if(![self.selectedRows containsObject:rowString])
             [self.selectedRows addObject:rowString];
    } else {

        if([self.selectedRows containsObject:rowString])
             [self.selectedRows removeObject:rowString];
    }

    eCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return eCell;
}
```

Hope it will helps you..

Answer (score 1):

You ought to remember every switch with on custom array or set.

NSMutableArray contained value for indexPath.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    BOOL checkBox = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    checkBox = !checkBox;
    NSNumber *saveCheckBox = [NSNumber numberWithBool:checkBox];
    [self.array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:saveCheckBox];

 }
```